# Using variable or class defined in other aspx file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

First of all, I'm noob using .NET.

I have a functional published .NET website in IIS, but I don´t have the source.
As I have to do some changes in the aspx pages, I want to create a vs project.

I created visual studio 2010 project, and copy and paste all the content to my new project (I don't know if this step is correct and if I have to do something more) but I'm having lots of errors about references.
Example:

File: secure/abc/main.aspx

```
<% @Page Language="VB" Explicit="True" Debug="False" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<!--#include virtual="Config.aspx" -->
<!--#include virtual="Render.aspx" -->

<script language="vb" runat="server">
    Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Render(sender, e)
    End Sub
</script>
<html><head></head><body>
    blah blah blah...
    <asp:Literal ID="TemplateHeader" runat="server"></asp:Literal> 
    blah blah blah...
</body></html>
```

File: secure/abc/Config.aspx

```
<script language="vb" runat="server">
    Public Class InitiatePage
        Public Shared Function GetHeader(sender As Object, e As EventArgs, RequestPath As String)
         blah blah blah
        ...
```

File: secure/abc/Render.aspx

```
<script language="vb" runat="server">
    Sub Render(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    TemplateHeader.Text = InitiatePage.GetHeader(sender, e, Request.FilePath)
...
```

In this case, errors are in Render.aspx:

> 'TemplateHeader' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its
> protection level.
>
> 'InitiatePage' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its
> protection level.

How can I repare this reference errors?

Do I need to include a reference in Render.aspx? If yes, why does works fine in its published way in IIS?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect this only "works" in its current form because of this: `<!--#include virtual="Render.aspx" -->`, which Visual Studio isn't going to process like IIS does.  This is *not* the ASP.NET way of structuring these things.  `TemplateHeader` exists on `main.aspx`, so it would be a property in the `Main` page class and would be used *only* in that class.  Other "sub pages" like this would likely be constructed as User Controls or perhaps pages which uses a common Master Page.

Answer (score 1):

When you include one file in another that way

```
<!--#include virtual="Config.aspx" -->
```

All it does it cause the page to render the contents of that file as part of the response, but it's not processing the contents of that file server-side (other than reading it and rendering it to the output.) So if you have server controls in that included file you can't refer to them. From the perspective of the server code, those controls don't exist.

If you want to create a partial page that's reused across multiple pages, the way to do that is with a [user control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

> A user control is a kind of composite control that works much like an
>   ASP.NET Web page—you can add existing Web server controls and markup
>   to a user control, and define properties and methods for the control.
>   You can then embed them in ASP.NET Web pages, where they act as a
>   unit.

In your project, Add -> New Item -> Web Forms User Control. That's going to create an .ascx file. You can add controls and content to that control just as you would with an .aspx page.

Then on the page where you want to display that user control, add the following after your page directive:

```
<% @Page Language="VB" Explicit="True" Debug="False" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="YourControl" Src="YourControl.ascx" %>
```

`TagPrefix` is just a prefix you select. `TagName` is the name you want to use for this type of control on the page. (Often we just use the name of the control.) `Src` is the path and file name of the .ascx file.

Then, wherever you want to add the control to the page, insert

```
<uc:YourControl id="SomeIdThatYouAssign" runat="server"/>
```

That's a quick version. The linked documentation is much more thorough.

Comment: Thanks. Could be another simpler way?  The problem is that I should change only the necesary because is a production web page, and there is a lot of pages if I want to use user controls instead.

Comment: Are you using a master page? That's how we usually address having controls that are present on every single page. That enables you to modify many aspects of your pages, including adding controls that appear on every page, without modifying the individual pages. The idea is that the pages would primarily contain their own content, but everything that would normally be "included" is on the master page.